# Why does "redirect to a file" is executed as user, even with sudo?

Tags: shell, sudo

I often encouter this problem and it really bugs me on why it is so. So let's take this example into account :

```
[me@localhost:~]$ sudo command > /some/file.log
```

As far as I know, this will not work if the `user` has no permission to write in `/some/file.log`, even if the command is executed as `sudo`. I found some workarounds on this website so that's not a problem, but I would like to know **what is the reason behind it ?** Why would the command be executed as `sudo`, and the redirection as user ? Any solid reason to back this up ?

Comment: As said in my post, I already knew how to make this work properly. My question was more about why is that so, and Anthon gave me the reason :)

Comment: @eyoung100 did you test that. I can not see how it can work, so I tested it, and it did not.

Comment: @eyoung100 you just repeated the command, that does not work, that was in your earlier comment (that you deleted).

Comment: I changed the directory to `root`, but I'll delete them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `sudo` the command `command`, the redirection of the output to `/some/file.log` is done by your current shell, which is running as the normal user.

What you could try in order to get the output written by `root` is:

```
sudo bash -c "command > /some/file.log"
```